PAM unable to dlopen(pam_lastlog.so) /usr/lib/security/pam_lastlog.so - PAM adding faulty module: pam_lastlog.so
I want to have autologin in Ubuntu 24.04 LTS for the user account user. So I changed the file /etc/systemd/system/getty.target.wants/getty@tty1.service.
Then I added this

[Service]
# the VT is cleared by TTYVTDisallocate
# The '-o' option value tells agetty to replace 'login' arguments with an
# option to preserve environment (-p), followed by '--' for safety, and then
# the entered username.
#ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty -o '-p -- \\u' --noclear %I $TERM
ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --autologin user --noclear %I $TERM <<----
Type=idle
Restart=always
RestartSec=0
UtmpIdentifier=%I
TTYPath=/dev/%I

But I could not achieve no autologin. Instead when I run journalctl -xeu getty@tty1.service then I got this red error. The error says that the file pam_lastlog.so is missing, which is true in this case.
PAM unable to dlopen(pam_lastlog.so) /usr/lib/security/pam_lastlog.so
PAM adding faulty module: pam_lastlog.so 

I'm guessing that this is the issue. So how can I solve this? I have already installed sudo apt-get install libpam-modules
So I tried to deactivate the error by adding a comment on
sudo nano /etc/pam.d/login

#session optional pam_lastlog.so

Then the error disappear, but still, no autologin!

Solved the issue!
I was on wrong tty. I must be on getty@ttySTM0.service, which was located at /run/systemd/generator....
